# Using Gsub in R to remove a string containing brackets

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `gsub` to remove certain parts of a string. However, I can't get it to work, and I think it's because the string to be removed contains brackets. Is there any way around this? Thanks for any help.

The command I want to use:

```
gsub('(4:4aCO)_','', '(5:3)_(4:4)_(5:3)_(4:4)_(4:4aCO)_(6:2)_(4:4a)')
```

Returns:

```
#"(5:3)_(4:4)_(5:3)_(4:4)_(4:4aCO)_(6:2)_(4:4a)"
```

Expected output:

```
#"(5:3)_(4:4)_(5:3)_(4:4)_(6:2)_(4:4a)"
```

A quick test to see if brackets were the problem:

```
gsub('te','', 'test')
#[1] "st"

gsub('(te)','', '(te)st')
#[1] "()st"
```

Comment: Do you need `gsub('\\(4:4aCO\\)','', '(5:3)(4:4)(5:3)(4:4)(4:4aCO)(6:2)_(4:4a)')` ?

Comment: You are correct. Parenthesis have special meanings in regexs.  You can either escape them in your regex or use fixed=TRUE as akrun suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can by placing the brackets inside the square brackets as `()` is a metacharacter

```
gsub('[(]4:4aCO[)]','', '(5:3)(4:4)(5:3)(4:4)(4:4aCO)(6:2)_(4:4a)')
```

Or with `fixed = TRUE` to evaluate the literal meaning of that character

```
gsub('(4:4aCO)','', '(5:3)(4:4)(5:3)(4:4)(4:4aCO)(6:2)_(4:4a)', fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Adding 'fixed=TRUE' gives the expected output, thanks a lot!